# Indian traveling to Ireland via the Netherlands

Tags: visas, schengen, netherlands, ireland

I have an Indian passport and I'm traveling to Ireland mid-June 2018. I will be staying in Amsterdam, the Netherlands, for 3 days, before flying to Ireland.

The [Ireland visa website](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist) tells me that I should have the visa from the country I'm coming from in my passport before I apply for it. In this case, it would be the Netherlands visa.

Under the section **"Travel to-and-from Ireland via a different country"**

> If relevant, apply for those countries' visas before you apply for an Irish visa. Your application for an Irish visa may be refused if your passport does not contain the expected visas.

However, the Netherlands Schengen [visa checklist (PDF)](http://www.vfsglobal.com/netherlands/india/pdf/Checklist-Tourist-NL.pdf) (Point #7.1) tells me that I need a valid visa to the destination I'm flying to from the Netherlands!

Which country's visa do I need to apply for first? I am going to be staying in Ireland for 8 days and Amsterdam for 3 days.

**Edit:** There is another section in the above page for the Ireland visa.

*If you do not get the expected visas before you apply for an Irish visa, explain why in your letter. The visa officer will include those reasons when reviewing your application.*

I have a Schengen short-stay visa for the Netherlands from last year (September 2017), which has expired. So I am planning to mention that in my letter included in the application for the Ireland visa. Since I have a Schengen Netherlands visa last year, there shouldn't be a problem getting the visa for it again. So I will apply for the Ireland visa first. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think get the Schengen visa first since that is your first destination. Once you have it, apply for the Ireland visa, as you'll have the required visa for the country you are coming from (Netherlands) when you are going to Ireland.

Your travel history means you will likely be approved for both visas, but if your personal or financial circumstances changed since last time then you might not be approved.

I admire your commitment: it's a lot of effort for a short visit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your kind words @user16259! I have already set an appointment date for the Ireland visa so I will be difficult for me to apply for the Netherlands visa first. I will update this thread regarding how the visa process went and if the Ireland embassy accepted the application. 
Unfortunately for Indians, this is the usual MO to visit most countries :)